# How can the Earth be used as a return path?

Tags: power, rf, transmission-line, telecommunications

I was reading an academic document and I came across this statement:

> Telegraphy, 1747 (a singe-wire line with the Earth as a return conductor – the first transmission line)

I can't imagine how that can work theoretically.
Wouldn't the signal just dissipate after reaching the destination?

Comment: Why would it dissipate? Current will take the path of least resistance to get back to where it started.

Comment: Farmers in America used their fence lines to communicate.

Comment: @Finbarr Current will not only take the path of least resistance, there will be more current on a path with low resistance and less current on a path with higher resistance.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Earth has high resistance so If I send a signal 1000 kms away, by the time it reaches back it would be attenuated, distorted and most of it lost wouldn't it? I don't even know if it will even reach the source back.

Comment: Have you done any research to understand what the resistance of the Earth is between two points? In any case, as long as the signal gets there in an understandable state it doesn't matter about the return.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted. I am a newbie in electrical engineering, not a pro. I always had trouble imagining anything realated to using ground as return path either for power or for RF, transmission line etc.

Comment: @MALLU I agree, it's a good question in general. Some members here might not like a question where the title is as long as the actual question, which looks like you haven't put much effort into it. Your first comment would easily fit into the question body ;) (I'm not the one who downvoted ;)

Comment: Earth or Ocean water is even used for pretty high DC return currents when a monopolar high voltage DC transmission is done with a single conductor under water cable. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltic_Cable Current is up to 1364 A, 600 MW 440 kV

Answer (score 3):

*"[Transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line)"* is a term of art.

An electromagnetic wave in a "radio" mode would expand from a point in a spherical manner (affected by objects and atmosphere), in the manner of a circular wave on a pond. There wouldn't be a "return".

A classical DC current on the other hand *requires* a return - it must flow in a continuous loop.

A transmission line is a combination of the two. It is a model in which an EM signal is transmitted as a pulse through a pair of conductors, one of which is out of phase with the other. The "positive" and "negative" halves of the signal emit opposite EM fields which cancel each other out at a distance from the transmission line, so the energy is *mostly* contained within the line. There is loss, but not as much as the spherical loss of RF energy in all directions.

Effectively you'd have half the signal travelling in the single telegraph line, and half the signal travelling in the nearby ground. Crucially, both travelling forwards and together, both absorbed in the reciever at the far end.

So the "return" is a slightly misleading word. The original signal does not "go out" one side and "return" the other. Instead it goes out both line and ground simultaneously in the same direction.

Comment: But we're talking about one-wire telegraphy back in 1747, where a current switched down the line from the originating end closes an electromagnet at the receiving end. That's a classical DC current switched at very low frequency, not an RF transmission.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask then what is the purpose of a ground in the transmission line then. If it does not return any signal

Comment: @Finbarr. Not DC strictly speaking as the initial few microseconds of the switched current implies a propagating EM wave travelling down the one-wire telegraph wire with the earth as a type of ground reference plane. This EM energy wave will reach steady "DC" mode once the EM wave settles, but has enough energy to close the EM-magnet. The essence here is to appreciate the fact that it is the initial, first micro-seconds "disturbance" that creates a propagating EM wave from A to B over many miles, and this EM energy transmits the message from A to B etc ...

Comment: @citizen +1. Assuming we're in the domain where classical electromagnetic models apply, Kirchoff's Current Law tells us that the current must have a return path. We call these things "circuits" because current flows in circles. Energy, however, has no such restriction. Poynting's theorem suggests that we attribute energy flow to the electromagnetic field that the current sets up, and it goes from transmitter to receiver.

Comment: @John Doty. Kirchhoff's laws can be understood as corollaries of Maxwell's equations in the low-frequency limit. They are accurate for DC circuits, and for AC circuits at frequencies where the wavelengths of electromagnetic radiation are very large compared to the circuits. The distances of telegraphy discussed (100s of kms) pertain more to the domain of "transmission" lines. There was never a DC current return path through earth for the one-wire system described, even though the source of energy of transmission was from a primitive battery...

Comment: @citizen I tell students that by using Kirchoff's laws they're pledging to account for all their induction and displacement current. Then, Kirchoff's laws apply at short wavelengths, although their ability to produce simple approximations declines.

Comment: @citizen Do you imagine that the charge transmitted by a one-wire telegraph simply builds up at the ends of the line?

Answer (score 3):

The resistance between two points on the earth can be very low, sufficiently low to make a telegraph work.

Consider the signal wire, it may have a cross section of only 1 mm<sup>2</sup>. Consider the ground between two points 100 km apart. For most of the path length, the width of the potential path for the current could be many km both wide and deep. That's an area of 10<sup>13</sup> or more than the wire case, which allows conduction to take place through very poorly conducting rock and soil. Many places have underground water, even if it's not apparent on the surface.

This just leaves the few metres close to the launch and receive points. These sort of earth return systems work best when the local ground is damp, and use long rods, possibly several, driven into the soil, for the electrodes. If the soil is dry, then 'watering' the rod will help. If there is a watercourse nearby, then a good connection is assured.